# How to implement Spark UDF class for a not yet supported programming language?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to implement a wrapper for Spark UDFs in an officially unsupported programming language (namely, [Julia](https://julialang.org/)). Previously, I already implemented [RDD API](https://github.com/dfdx/Spark.jl/blob/master/jvm/sparkjl/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/julia/JuliaRDD.scala), so running workers and communication between processes isn't a problem. However, it's unclear for me which interfaces should be implemented by a wrapper class to make it work with Catalyst.

I started with [PythonUDF](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3a299aa6480ac22501512cd0310d31a441d7dfdc/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/PythonUDF.scala#L52-L76) which implements `Expression` interface and holds `PythonFunction` to be called on input data. However, `PythonUDF` doesn't implement the `eval()` method (the class extends `Unevaluable` trait) and thus is not responsible for executing by itself. Instead, there are several additional classes like [ArrowEvalPythonExec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/python/ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala#L62) which do the actual job. But what is in between?

To make this question more concrete, I'd like to know any of these:

1. How does `PythonUDF` turn into actual code?
2. What is the easiest way to implement similar behavior for a new programming language?